# how to retrieve the size of a CCSprite that contains other CCSprites

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i need to make a group of collectibles coins within my test game..
so i made a class that have this method:

```
+(CCSprite *)groupWithArray:(NSArray*)positions
{
    CCSprite *coins = [[[CCSprite alloc] init] autorelease];
    for (NSValue *pos in positions) {
        Coin *coin = [Coin sprite];
        [coin setPosition:[pos CGPointValue]];
        [coins addChild:coin];
    }
    return coins;
}
```

(the `Coin` class extends `CCSprite` and the `sprite` method returns a `spriteWithFile:` that have 50px for both width and height)

then i call this method

```
CCSprite *cgroup = [CoinsGroup groupWithArray:positions];
```

now i need to know `cgroup`'s width..
i've tried:

```
NSLog(@"coins group width: %f",cgroup.contentSize.width);
NSLog(@"coins group width: %f",cgroup.contentSizeInPixels.width);
NSLog(@"coins group width: %f",cgroup.boundingBox.size.width);
NSLog(@"coins group width: %f",cgroup.boundingBoxInPixels.size.width);
```

but all of them return `coins group width: 0.000000`

why is that?..

Answer (score 0):

contentSize and boundingBox refer to the size of the image that the sprite has attached. So, in your case, you don't have an image on coins, is just a container (you maybe should use a plain CCNode).